# JDBC Connection object automatically closes after the static block is executed and how to modularize the code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a class that is calling a database class to add entries to the database. The problem is that whenever I am adding a tuple to the database, I have to create a new Connection and a Statement object.

One hack I thought to get around this is to place the initialization of the Connection and the Statement object in a static block. And directly run the command statement.executeUpdate(sqlStatement).

But this gives an error that the Connection object is not initialized.

The code for this is as follows:

```
class Database{
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "....";  
    static final String DB_URL = "...";

    static final String USER = ".....";
    static final String PASS = ".....";
    static Connection conn  = null;   // Connection object for creating a connection with the Database
    static Statement  stmt  = null;   // Statement  object to  run queries on first table in  Database

    static{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            stmt  = conn.createStatement();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){  //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{  //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null){
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException se2){
                System.out.println("caught a SQLException " + se2 + " AND NOTHING CAN BE DONE ABOUT IT");
                // nothing we can do
            }
            try{
                if(conn!=null){
                    conn.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void runSqlCommand(String command)throws java.lang.Exception{
        stmt.executeUpdate(command); // This gives an error that connection is not initialized.
    }

}
```

I want to know how can I modularize the code so that I can just call a runSqlCommand function and the sql code is executed without having to create a connection and a statement each time.

Also please tell by how much should the performance be improved if I initialize the objects only once and not for every sql command.

Comment: **Why** don't you want to create a connection and a statement every time? Doing so is generally cleaner IMO (and avoids having so much code in class initialization, waiting to break the whole system due to a single transient failure). Use a connection pool to handle caching of connections and statements automatically, so your app code doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the connection in the static initializer block and you are closing it at the end of the block, so whenever your class will loaded, you'll always have your connection initialized and then closed, I think you need to move out the code which you have written in the finally block.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correctly telling you that there is an execution path via which 'stmt' doesn't get initialized, namely if you get an exception opening the connection.

But in any case as you're carefully closing both the statement and the connection in the static block, the entire exercise is completely pointless in the first place.

I recommend a connection pool, and opening and closing connections as and when you actually need them. Much more robust than trying to keep a single connection open for the life of the process, and much kinder to the database than trying to tie up a single connection all day.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modularize the code, separate the connection management code in some other files, like you can use the DAO pattern, from where you get the initialized connection, and once you are done, close the connection through the DAO helper method.